# Why do I have to put the project name when importing tasks when using Django with Celery?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I just installed and configured Celery with RabbitMQ for a Django project and I was having an issue running tasks when I imported them like so:

```
from someapp.tasks import SomeTask
```

It worked when I added the project name:

```
from myproject.someapp.tasks import SomeTask
```

I tried adding this into the settings.py file but it doesn't change anything:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("myproject.someapp.tasks",)
```

I'm fine with leaving the project name on the import line since it works but I'd like to know if there's a way around it or why it has to be that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ("myproject.someapp", )
```

Instead you should add the directory containing the apps on the Python path (the project in 
this case), and simply do

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ("someapp", )
```

IMHO this makes more sense for an "app" anyway.

Comment: This is good to know and I made the change to my settings file but now the task does not fire anymore. Everything else still works but the task does not run.

Comment: does not run? Is it listed in the task list part of the splash screen when starting celeryd?